# Applying Threading to Web Parsing Results in Errors for Sublinks of Parent link

Tags: python, multithreading, url, python-requests, multiprocessing

I created a web parser that parses the contents of a list of base URLS first, gets all their respective sublinks, and then iterates through those sublinks, again gets the sublinks of those sublinks and so forth. I want to apply either multiprocessing or multithreading so I can parallelize the request calls. Since multi-threading share the same memory object, I went with that over multiprocessing. Unfortunately, I am experiencing a problem that might be caused by multiple calls to urls that are derived from the same parent per thread? Does anyone know how best parallelize my web parser without running into the below error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dialog/share?app_id=132746074315&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engadget.com%2F2018%2F09%2F28%2Fepa-dissolve-science-advisory-office%2F (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc2a9132eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)): Could not access this webpage: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=132746074315&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engadget.com%2F2018%2F09%2F28%2Fepa-dissolve-science-advisory-office%2F
```

This how I am applying multi-threading

```
 def main(self):

        self.getBaseURLs()

        while self.idx <= self.drillDown:
            urls = self.getURLs()
            threads = [threading.Thread(target=self.crawlPages, args=(url,)) for url in urls]
            for thread in threads:
                thread.start()
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()

            # p = pool.ThreadPool(cpu_count()-1)
            # p.map(self.crawlPages, urls)
            # p.close()
            # p.join()

            self.idx += 1
            self.urlCollection[self.idx] = self.sublinks
            self.sublinks = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dude. I hope you are doing well.

I think I had the same problem a few weeks ago.

### My scenario:

I was mocking some HTTP requests to create a fake app in python, and when I was trying to use thread to do these requests in parallel, I received the same error that you described above.

So search for another way to do this and find this lib:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html, and changed the code to this:

```
from . import fixtures
import requests
import requests_mock
import json
import random
import time
import asyncio


async def __get_juducial_records_by_social_number(social_number):

    url = format('http://nationaljudicialrecords/check?id=%s' % social_number)
    record, record_index = fixtures.check_national_judicial_data_mock(
        social_number)

    mock_latance = random.randrange(0, 7, 2)

    time.sleep(mock_latance)

    if record == None:
        with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
            m.get(url, text="NOT FOUND", status_code=404)
            response = requests.get(url)

            return response
    else:
        with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
            text = json.dumps(fixtures.national_judicial_redords[record_index])
            m.get(url, text=text, status_code=200)
            response = requests.get(url)

            return response


async def __get_registry_by_social_number(social_number):

    url = format(
        'https://nationalregistryidentification/check?id=%s' % social_number)
    record, record_index = fixtures.check_national_registry_data_mock(
        social_number)

    mock_latance = random.randrange(0, 7, 2)

    time.sleep(mock_latance)

    if record == None:
        with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
            m.get(url, text="NOT FOUND", status_code=404)
            response = requests.get(url)

            return response
    else:
        with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
            text = json.dumps(fixtures.national_registry_records[record_index])
            m.get(url, text=text, status_code=200)
            response = requests.get(url)

            return response


async def get_national_records_coroutines(social_number):

    result = await asyncio.gather(
        __get_juducial_records_by_social_number(social_number),
        __get_registry_by_social_number(social_number)
    )
    return result
```

Do you see?

I used `async def` to declare my functions, and after that I used the `asyncio.gather()` method to call these coroutines here:

```
async def get_national_records_coroutines(social_number):

    result = await asyncio.gather(
        __get_juducial_records_by_social_number(social_number),
        __get_registry_by_social_number(social_number)
    )
    return result
```

And it worked fine.

You can get more information on this link:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id2